# php-if filesize exceeds more than 5mb file size becomes zero and no error is shown

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, upload

I am facing some problem with upload process.

if file size exceeds 5mb, I am not able to get the error message or say validation are not showing proper. Even if validation fails, still it gets inserted in to db.

if i check the file size above 5mb it shows zero.

```
            if(isset($_FILES['FileupName'])){
            $file=$_FILES['FileupName'];
            $ext_str = "gif,jpg,jpeg,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,txt,pdf,zip,tar,xls,xlsx";
            $allowed_extensions=explode(',',$ext_str);
            $max_file_size = 5000000;
            $ext = substr($file['name'], strrpos($file['name'], '.') + 1); 
            $file_check_error = 0 ;
            if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions) ) {
            echo "Only ".$ext_str." files allowed to upload."."<br>"; // exit the script by warning
            $file_check_error = 1 ;
            }
```

Here is my problem:

```
            if($file['size']>=$max_file_size){

            echo "Only the file less than "."5 "."mb  allowed to upload."."<br>"; // exit the script by warning
            $file_check_error = 1 ;
        }

            $path = $file['name'];
```

This peace of code if for inserting to db.

```
 $item['FileupName']= $file['name'];
 $item['userid']=$item_valid;
 $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
 $item['id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

cont..

```
        if ($file_check_error == 0){

        $item['FileupName']= $file['name'];
        $item['userid']=$item_valid;
        $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
        $item['id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

creating directory based on application id.

```
$path_user = '/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';
if (!file_exists($path_user)) {
if (mkdir( $path_user,0777,false )) {
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path_user.$path)){
echo"inside 2"."<br>";
echo"Your File Successfully Uploaded";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you verify if the server (I am supposing Apache) has a different max size value for upload? If so, this may be an issue (You might be allowing more than the server allows). It is also important noticing that 5 megabytes is not `5000000` but `52428800` Bits.

Comment: @Bonatti ok..i will check for that.

Comment: @Bonatti iam working on wordpress